# IMACROS How to do selective commands in an iim macro file

Tags: loops, random, imacros

Have following code in an IIM

```
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=www.abc. com
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="16681" BUTTON=4
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="35353" BUTTON=1
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="26541" BUTTON=2
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="32342" BUTTON=1
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="04554" BUTTON=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:CLICKSELECT
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:CLICKSELECT
```

There are 5 EVENT commands above, in between other commands
Instead of doing all EVENT commands in every run of IIM, need that only some for e.g. 3 random EVENT commands get processed and not all.

Needed so that this EVENT commands clicks happen a random number of times and not all of them equally
Thanks

Comment: I doubt strongly of someone can do this without JavaScript.

Comment: @Shugar I am  of if i get solution with Javascript...can you help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var M;
var clkSelArr = [["16681",4], ["35353",1], ["26541",2], ["32342",1], ["04554",3]];

iimPlayCode("TAB T=1" + "\n" + "URL GOTO=www.abc. com");

// random number of clicks is between min and max
var min = 3;
var max = 5;
var rndNumClk = min + Math.floor((max - min + 1)*Math.random());
for (i = 1; i <= rndNumClk; i++) {
    var rndNum = Math.floor(clkSelArr.length*Math.random());
    M = "EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=\"" + clkSelArr[rndNum][0] + "\" BUTTON=" + clkSelArr[rndNum][1];
    iimPlayCode(M);
}

M = "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:CLICKSELECT" + "\n";
M += "TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:CLICKSELECT";
iimPlayCode(M);
```

Comment: Hello I am sorry for late reply but some grave family issue. though i havent tried your code yet..i feel it seems fine and wud be working..but there is an issue. Actually these EVENT Commands which i have in a IIm are not just 4-5 (they are say 50-100) and i have to work with 20-30 such iims on regular basis.So it wont be easy for me to copy that EVENT code of so many lines and post into var clkSelArr  (except if you tell me some automated way :P ).  SO what do you advise in such scenario.

Comment: I can convert IIM code to JAVASCRIPT easily though using a automated tool But adding all those numbers to  down vote accept var clkSelArr  would be a difficult process you see :(

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to use a csv-file in order to keep all needed values for these EVENT commands and read them into the array-variable ‘clkSelArr’. As to “20-30 such iims” and converting to ‘.js’: maybe it would be easier to define variables with ‘iimSet()’ and to run your ‘iims’ with iimPlay("macroNN.iim") without any converting. But, of course, all depends on your skills…

Comment: Thanks for replying. is there any easy way to copy those 50-100 event ID from each usual 30-40 IIM code and put them into JS as you purposed. Can it be done in some easier way than manually doing it all?

Comment: I advise you to contact me via e-mail ( shugarjs@gmail.com ) with the purpose to define more exactly the problem and to communicate in more convenient way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use iim macro code like this:

for each button generate the selector id randomly and set the probability by adding more 0's to the array.

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var letters = ['16681','0','0']; var string = ''; for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){string += letters[parseInt(Math.random() * 3)]}; string")
```

and then call the event with ignore error flag turned on

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR={{!VAR1}} BUTTON=4
```

do this for each button and you end up with (in this example) a 1/3 chance for each button to be clicked.

If you configure the random to contain all 5 button options with some zeros and run it you can also get two clicks on the same button